# How to make hexagon diagram from Smart diagram package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, smartdiagram

I know **How to make a smart diagram** from Smart Diagram Package, but "How to make hexagon diagram from Smart Diagram package" and

**How to change from bubble diagram to be hexagon diagram?**

like this :

[image: pentagram diagram from Microsoft Office Word 2013]

and I copy-paste code for bubble diagram from Smart Diagram Package document

```
\begin{center}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
Build a program,Set up,Run,Analyze,Modify~/\\ Add,Check
}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Do you mean [hexagon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon) when you say [pentagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram)? Otherwise I'm rather confused by your question...

Comment: Ya .... Hexagon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you speak from a hexagon I added a sixth element to the list.

I’m using the `connected constellation diagram` diagram and change the styles for `planet`s  and `satellite`s so that they use the `regular polygon` shape from the `shapes.geometric` library.

The `connection planet satellite` style that is applied to the `\path` with the `edge` that connects the “satellites” is set up in a way that it draws the trapezoid connection (this could probably be made smarter so that the parallel sides use the side length of one of the hexagons).

For some reason, `\smartdiagram` only allows the diagram type as its first argument (the one in brackets `[ ]` (which is not optional)), so I had to give the options beforehand. Usually, this should be grouped (your `center` environment or a `figure` environment does this already), I left this group out for this example.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  planet/.append style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6},
  satellite/.append style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6},
  every picture/.append style={rotate=30},
  connection planet satellite/.style={
    bend right/.style=,
    every edge/.style={fill=\col},
    to path={
      \pgfextra
        \path[draw=none, fill=none] (\tikztostart) 
          -- coordinate[at start] (@start@) coordinate[at end] (@target@) (\tikztotarget);
      \endpgfextra
      \ifnum\xi<\maxsmitem % to disable the last arrow
        ($(@start@)!.6cm!90:(@target@)$) -- ($(@target@)!.25cm!-90:(@start@)$)
          -- ($(@target@)!.25cm!90:(@start@)$) -- ($(@start@)!.6cm!-90:(@target@)$)
          -- cycle
      \fi}}}
\smartdiagram[connected constellation diagram]{
  Build a program,
  Set up,
  Run,
  Analyze,
  Modify/\\Add,
  Check,
  and a sixth}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Error ...  but since i copy- paste 3 file this following  : 1. smartdiagramlibrarycore.commands.code.tex, 2. smartdiagramlibrarycore.definitions.code.tex, 3. smartdiagramlibrarycore.styles.code.tex  and i am succes convert my file, Why ??

Comment: @HirWanto Since you accepted the answer, am I right to assume that the answer works for you? I can’t make much sense of your comment.

Comment: ya... you right ...

Comment: @HirWanto: if you get that error message, very likely you have an outdated package version. From version 0.3, to not have a unique, enormous, file .sty, the package is divided into libraries. Specifically, the 3 `core` libraries are the fundamental ones which contain and extend the previous version of the package.