# How can I generate customized smart diagrams?

Tags: smartdiagram

Actually, I am unable to comment on any post so far. Therefore, I have to ask the questions in the separate thread.

I want to customize the bubble nodes in a bubble diagram and found one [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138653/how-to-make-hexagon-diagram-from-smart-diagram-package) discussing it. But I want to generate something similar to the attached image. How can I generate an image (similar to attached) using smart diagrams?

[image]

I have following MWE (derived from above mentioned thread):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
planet/.append style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6},
satellite/.append style={rectangle},
every picture/.append style={rotate=30},
connection planet satellite/.style={
bend right/.style=,
every edge/.style={fill=\col},
to path={
  \pgfextra
    \path[draw=none, fill=none] (\tikztostart) 
      -- coordinate[at start] (@start@) coordinate[at end] (@target@) 
 (\tikztotarget);
 \endpgfextra
}}}
\smartdiagram[connected constellation diagram]{
 Build a program, Set up, Run,  Analyze,  Modify/\\Add,  Check,  and a sixth}
\end{document}
```

How can I customize the appearance of bubble nodes similar to shown in the attached image (especially I want circles green and red with + and - sign)?

I hope it clears the question.

Comment: [This](https://ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram) might help you, since you're using that tag. Unless the tagging is wrong. Also:

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The easier it is to copy and test your code, the more likely your question will be answered and can help others in a similar situation.

Comment: Hi, @thymaro Thank you for your suggestion. I have added MWE, hope it helps in finding the solution.

Comment: In the example image, some of the text is centered, some ragged right and some ragged left.  Just how smart is this diagram going to have to be?  (Or to put it another way, just how lazy is the writer as opposed to the programmer having to set this up?)